# Ng-disabled not working with AngularStrap's version of the Bootstrap date and time picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the [AngularStrap version](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers) of the Bootstrap datepicker and timepicker in my AngularJS app. I'm trying to make the date picked in the datepicker to a required field and have the following code:

```
<form name="timepickerForm" role="form" novalidate>
   <input type="text" ng-model="timeDateInput" bs-datepicker required>
   <input type="text" ng-model="timeDateInput" bs-timepicker required>
   <input type="text" ng-model="title">

   <button type="button" ng-click="handleStart()" ng-disabled="timepickerForm.$invalid">Start</button>

</form>
```

The button does not get disabled even though it has no input. If I put `required`on the last and regular input, the button gets disabled, so there's nothing wrong with the form or button. I can't find any documentation on the AngularStrap page or in their code to see if it is  possible or not.

Does anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: Can you put together a quick plunker? I've tried on a quick plunker and I got to work what you need...

Comment: Wow, I did the same and it worked. I set it to an empty string in my controller, and that somehow disabled the validating. Works great now, thanks!

Comment: Great to know! You should add that as an answer and mark as answered so if anyone ever looks for this, they'll have the answer. Sometimes it's better to try something in isolation since that clears out most of the complexity of the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I, in my controller, set $scope.timeDateInput to an empty string at initialization and that disabled the "required" validation. Once I removed that (or set it to undefined instead) it started working.